# Set a default cell to be highlighted in UIableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a split view and in the master view there is table view.
In the first opening, one of the cell from the master will be shown in the detail page. 
I want, when it's open, its cell should be highlighted. For example in the iOS setting on iPad, when you open it, "General" cell is highlighted and is opened in the detail page.

In the `viewDidLoad`, I wrote it, bit it's not working

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
}
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Do you call `tableView.reloadData()` in master view controller?

Comment: does it need to reloadata? because what I want will be happen when the page is open.

Comment: If you call `tableView.reloadData()` table view will unhighlight the cell. So if you have `tableView.reloadData()` in your code, comment it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableViews/UICollectionViews are mostly nil in viewDidLoad(), once the view is loaded, you'll be able to highlight your cells in your tableView.

you can either do :

```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0)
    self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
     }
}
```

or

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0)
 tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true,   scrollPosition: .none)

}
```